# How to pass a bash array into expect

Tags: expect

I have a shell script that passes a array variable to expect. But, in the expect part, it only takes the first argument and says "couldn't read file `--server`: no such file or directory"

below is the example program:-

Here i want the complete value of `${CMPREQUEST_ARGS[@]}` which is 
cmpclient `--ir --server 10.10.10.10 --port 4040`

```
CMPREQUEST=($CMPCLIENT "${CMPREQUEST_ARGS[@]}")

echo "TEST:${CMPREQUEST[@]}:TEST"   //echo prints the value of ${CMPREQUEST[@]} correctly.

expect -c "
log_file -noappend -a \"/srv/Log/log/cmpclient-$app_id.log\"
log_user 1
set RET_VAL 1
set timeout 86400

puts "TEST2:${CMPREQUEST[@]}:TEST2"  

spawn \${CMPREQUEST[@]}
expect {
  -re \"SUCCESS\:\ write\ X509\" {
      set RET_VAL 0
  }
  timeout { set RET_VAL 1 }
}
exit \$RET_VAL
"
exit $?
```

I am getting this error in spawn
couldn't read file `--server`: no such file or directory

Please guide..Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you do it manually, how you will invoke your process which you are trying to spawn ? Post the complete command/output of the execution.

Answer (score 0):

This boils down to quoting hell. Use a shell here-doc to hold the expect code, then you don't need to escape all the "interior" quotes. Your main issue is the spawn command, where you are preventing the shell from expanding the array.

Try this:

```tcl
expect <<END_EXPECT
    log_file -noappend -a /srv/Log/log/cmpclient-$app_id.log
    log_user 1
    set RET_VAL 1
    set timeout 86400

    puts "TEST2:${CMPREQUEST[@]}:TEST2"  

    spawn ${CMPREQUEST[@]}
    expect {
        -re {SUCCESS: write X509} {
            set RET_VAL 0
        }
        timeout { set RET_VAL 1 }
    }
    exit \$RET_VAL
END_EXPECT
```

Only the expect variable `RET_VAL` needs to be protected from the shell.